# Visual Studio 2012 Beta - Error when deploying the app

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I have installed Windows 8 OS RP version and visual Studio 2012 beta version. But i'm getting the following error when deploying the package.

**Error:**

> Windows cannot install package xxxxx, because this package requires a
>   higher Windows version. The package requested Windows version 6.2 with
>   AppModel version 1, while the current Windows version is 6.2 with
>   AppModel version 0. (0x80073cfd).

How can I resolve this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason for using the beta of VS instead of the full release version?

Comment: I am having the same problem, but with Visual Studio Express 2012 on Windows 8 RP. I used the registry workaround to get it installed in the first place.

Comment: i have the same problem, still unsolved. Did you find a fix? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701751/microsoft-universal-apps-and-unit-testing-trouble-with-appmodel-version

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating new project and the carrying old files to the new project?